# How can I programatically create a binary Apple Double file in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, osx-snow-leopard, file-format

How can I create/write a binary [apple double file](http://www.nulib.com/library/FTN.e000023.htm) programatically in C/C++?

Ideally it would be nice if there is sample code that inputs what you want to go into the double file and then it encodes the file and writes it out for you.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone who knows anything about creating/modifying apple double files would respond to my post.

Comment: Ideally, don't. They're thoroughly obsolete.